# showing $\mu(\lim\sup_{n\to\infty} E_n) = 0.$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ be a measure space. Suppose $E_n\in \mathcal{M}$ such that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu(E_n) < \infty$$ show $\mu(\lim\sup_{n\to\infty} E_n) = 0.$

Also, how can I prove or give a counterexample of the conclusion if the hypothesis is replaced with $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu(E_n)^2 < \infty$$

Can I prove this by Fatou's Lemma? Thank you

Comment: Yes, Fatou lemma actually works. Besides, this theorem is precisely Borel-Cantelli lemma: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Bernard comments, the first part is actually the statement of Borel-Cantelli lemma.

For the second part, as Stella mentions, we may want to find a series which is not convergent but the series consists of square of its terms is convergent. The series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}$ will satisfy this condition.

So we need to construct a sequence of sets $\{E_n\}$ s.t. $\mu(E_n)=\frac{1}{n}, \forall n\ge1.$ Also, we want that $\mu(\lim\sup_{n\to\infty} E_n) \neq 0.$

To construct a concrete example, we may need a proposition.

**Proposition: For every real number x, there exists a sequence $x_1,x_2,x_3,...$ of integers such that $$x=x_1+\frac{x_2}{2!}+\frac{x_3}{3!}+\cdot\cdot\cdot \,,$$ where $x_1$ can be any integer, but for $n\ge2,x_n\in\{0,1,...,n-1\}.$ Furthermore, if we require that the partial sums be strictly smaller than x, then such a representation is unique.**

A proof can be found here: https://blogs.ams.org/mathgradblog/2017/09/20/real-numbers-base-factorials-by-product/

From the proposition and its proof, it's easy to see that, if $x\in(0,1)$, being an irrational number, then we can find an unique sequence $x_1,x_2,x_3,...$ s.t. $x_1=0$ and $$x=\frac{x_2}{2!}+\frac{x_3}{3!}+\cdot\cdot\cdot \,,$$ with $x_n\in\{0,1,...,n-1\},\forall n\ge2.$

Also note that, if $x$ is an irrational number, then the corresponding series will consist of infinitely many terms. (N.B. This is crucial to our construction, which makes sure the construction process will not terminate in finite steps.)

Our example will be given in the language of probability space, but in essence, it can be easily converted into the language of general measure theory.

We define the event $E_1=\{\text{pick a random irrational number $x$ in $(0,1)$, $x_1$ is $0$}. \}$. Then it's clear that $P(E_1)=1.$

For each $n\ge 2,$ define event $E_n=\{\text{pick a random irrational number $x$ in $(0,1)$, $x_n$ is $0$}. \}$. Then it's also clear that $P(E_n)=\frac{1}{n}.$

Note that these events are **mutually independent**.

By the second Borel-Cantelli lemma(c.f. [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel–Cantelli_lemma#Converse_result](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma#Converse_result)), we conclude that $P(\lim\sup_{n\to\infty} E_n)=1\neq 0.$

So, even though $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu(E_n)^2 < \infty$, we may still have $\mu(\lim\sup_{n\to\infty} E_n)=1\neq 0.$

$$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$

Comment: I think this example might be incorrect, as the $\limsup$ of pairwise disjoint sets is actually the empty set. This is further shown in your proof, where there is a error in applying continuity from above, because if $\mu(\bigcup_{n=k}^\infty E_n)=\infty$ for all $k$, then the sequence of sets does not satisfy the conditions for continuity from above.

Comment: @varpi Yea, you are right. I am thinking about how to fix it.

Comment: @varpi Hi Varpi, I've edited my answer and given a new example which I believe should be correct. And if you also agree that it's correct, may I ask you to withdraw the vote-down action? Thanks.

Comment: this looks correct, well done!

Answer (score 1):

It is a very general and very useful theorem of calculus that if $\sum a_i < \infty$ then it must be that $\lim\sup a_i = 0$. To get your result from this theorem, simply apply subadditivity.

For the counter example, can you think of a series such that $\sum a_i^2$ converges
and $\sum a_i$ diverges?

Comment: No I am unable to see it clearly yet :(

Comment: The tough part of the construction of the counter example is not about coming up with such a series, and it is how to relate such a series to sets.

Comment: @shiloh.otis were you able to answer the first part of the problem with my hint? Or are you struggling with that too.

Answer (score 1):

Proof of the first part:

The result you mention is the first Borel-Cantelli Lemma. First recall that
$$\limsup_n E_n = \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \bigcup_{k=n}^\infty E_k.$$
By continuity from above (check the conditions as an exercise) and sub-additivity, we have
$$\mu\left(\limsup_n E_n\right) = \lim_n\mu\left(\bigcup_{k=n}^\infty E_k\right)\leq \lim_n \left(\sum_{k=n}^\infty \mu(E_k)\right).$$
Note that last term is the tail of a convergent series, hence it converges to zero.

For the second part see Sam Wong's solution.